# multidimensional array as key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
    $dept = array();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($result as $row){
       array_push($dept, 
             array(
                'id'=>$row['Dept'], 
                'cCode'=>$row['ShortDesc'], 
                'cDesc'=>$row['LongDesc']
             )
          )
       );
   }
```

my prob in these code is how can i get the data (value of ['ShortDesc'] & ['LongDesc']) considering ['id'] as the key....

below is my sample data:

`**id     ShortDesc    LongDesc**
C        BSA          Bachelor of Science in Accountancy
C        BSCS         Bachelor of Science in Computer Science
M        MBA          Master in Business Administration`

when I input `C` as the id then the result must `BSA - Bachelor of .......` and `BSCS - Bachelor...`

Comment: Just a side note: _"f you use `array_push()` to add one element to the array it's better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function."_ (http://php.net/array_push)

Comment: Are you saying the code above does not work, or are you saying you want to use the `id` you already have to get other data from another table????

Comment: If your query is only returning `1 row` when you expect `2 rows` then show us the query as well as the above code

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, the code does work...i just want to use the `id` to get the other data....the query returns more than 1 row....20+......you can revise the code if you have better idea...thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds very simple, all your code is currently doing is transposing those three fields from your DB to a new structure within your array. To get the data back out you simply iterate and inspect the ID until you find it:

```
foreach($dept as $current) {
    if ($current['id'] == 'whatever') {
        $cCode = $current['cCode'];
        $cDesc = $current['cDesc'];
        break;
    }
}

echo "$cCode $cDesc" . PHP_EOL;
```

EDIT:

I missed your duplicate key issues, as per below comment.

```
$res = [];
foreach($dept as $current) {
    if ($current['id'] == 'whatever') {
        $res[] = $current;
    }
}

print_r($res);
```

Is that more helpful;?

Comment: Wouldn't for for his use case if you have the `break`, ID isn't unique so when you break early you're potentially missing matching candidates later in the `$dept` array.

Comment: Haha, oh yeah, apologies for presuming uniqueness! Surely the questioner can just build an array of results? I'll update my answer..

Answer (score 1):

Potentially you could use something like this:

```
function filterByID($id, $haystack){
    $matched = array();
    foreach ($haystack as $array) {
        if ($array['id'] === $id) {
            $matched[] = $array;
        }
    }

    return $matched;
}
```

Be warned, the `$id` that you pass in is **case-sensitive.**

Can see it working here: https://ideone.com/yDlY6g

The function will essentially return to you a filtered version of the Array, so the array will only contain arrays where the ID matches your search criteria.

You could then print out those with a loop, here's a quick example:

```
$filtered = filterByID('C', $dept);
foreach ($filtered as $department) {
    echo $department['cCode'];
    echo $department['cDesc'];
}
```

Hope that helps.